# Extract values from selected columns and rows in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark

Spark 3.0

I would like to extract specific values from selected columns into a print function from a spark DF onto my juypter sub-window.
I will be doing a for loop so I can automate the monthly files.

So for an example, print('Average salary for a male in company A as an IT is 26000').

I tried x['company'][0][0] for example, but I am not getting the value I needed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for.

```
df.select('company').collect()[0][0]
```